# Weight scale integration with c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I want to read from a weight scale using a serial port, and add that value to a textbox in a c# windows application. On the button being clicked I connect to the serial port and begin listening.  I've used following code but get no result,

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;          //<-- necessary to use "SerialPort"
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComPortTests
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort _serialPort;         //<-- declares a SerialPort Variable to be used throughout the form
        private const int BaudRate = 9600;      //<-- BaudRate Constant. 9600 seems to be the scale-units default value

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();     //<-- Reads all available comPorts
            foreach (var portName in portNames)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(portName);                  //<-- Adds Ports to combobox
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;                        //<-- Selects first entry (convenience purposes)
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //<-- This block ensures that no exceptions happen
            if(_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
                _serialPort.Close();
            if (_serialPort != null)
                _serialPort.Dispose();
            //<-- End of Block

            _serialPort = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);       //<-- Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
            _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;       //<-- this event happens everytime when new data is received by the ComPort
            _serialPort.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen
            textBox1.Text = "Listening on " + _serialPort.PortName + "...\r\n";
        }

        private delegate void Closure();

        private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)     //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
                BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself
            else
            {
                while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
                {
                    textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());
                    //<-- bytewise adds inbuffer to textbox
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `SerialPortOnDataReceived` event handler ever get called?  Do you get the "Listening on .." text but then nothing else?  Can you verify that you receive data from the scale through a serial terminal, without having to send it anything?

Comment: no, the event is not generating

Comment: Can you check if you're getting data from the scale through a serial port terminal program (like teraterm)?  Do you have to send anything to get a value back?  What is the make/model of the scale?

Comment: yes, i've used *hyperterminal* for checking the scale, i have to send *W* as signal and in response i get the weight in hyper terminal.

Comment: **CAS PD-II** is the scale.

Comment: Sir, i've taken a serialPort control, done all the setting as you have mentioned, and on button click i've done this code

`serialPort1.Open();
            serialPort1.WriteLine("W");
            serialPort1.DataReceived += SerialPort1_DataReceived;`

Comment: on data received event i've tried to get values, but unable to get, i've stepped in visual studio but event is not generating, Please help me if you have any working code

Comment: Sorry I wish I had a scale to test with.  You should do `serialPort1.DataReceived += SerialPort1_DataReceived;` before `serialPort1.WriteLine("W");`.  Checkout the code here: http://itrelations.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-read-weight-scale-via-serial.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Hyperterminal guide on the CAS website (http://www.cas-usa.com/cas-usa.com/media/PD-II%20Using%20Hyperterminal.pdf) I see two things you probably need to change in your code.

1) In the guide it shows the COM port settings as 9600 bps, 7 data bits, even parity, 1 stop bit, and no flow control.  When the COM port is being created in the code it's using slightly different settings.  It uses whatever baud rate is entered, 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit, and no flow control.

```
In guide: 9600 bps    | 7 data bits | even parity | 1 stop bit | no flow control  
In code : entered bps | 8 data bits | no parity   | 1 stop bit | no flow control
```

So based on the guide, your serial port constructor should be like this:

```
_serialPort = SerialPort p = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text, 9600, Parity.Even, 7, StopBits.One);
```

2) The second thing is that the guide mentions pressing a capital "W" followed by the enter key to get the weight in hyperterminal.  In your code you're not writing anything out on the serial port.  After you open the serial port try:

```
_serialPort.WriteLine("W");
```

This will only display the weight once.  If you want the weight to constantly update then you can send another "W" after you get the first weight back.